# Identify the elements returned by different processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Consider the following situation:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
      self.b_list = []

   def add_element(b)
      self.b_list.append(b)

class B:
   def __init__(self,x):
      self.x = x

class C:
   def __init__(self,a,other_data):
      self.a = a
   def find_new_b(self):
      ....


def solve(c):
   return c.find_new_b()
```

Each instance of `class A` has a list of instances of `class B`, that are added in an incremental way.

I need to iterate over all the instances of `class A` and find for each of them a new element of `class B`.

I'm using `multiprocessing` to do that

```
list_of_c_elements = [...]
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(solve, list_of_c_elements)
```

**The problem**

In results I have a list of results and I would like to understand of which instance of `class A` the new instance of `class B` belongs. Each instance of `class B` is generic, and I would like to keep the two classes decoupled.

**Considered solution**

Change `solve()` to:

```
def solve(c):
   return (c.a, c.find_new_b())
```

I have to compare all the elements of `class A` I have with the one returned (very inefficient).
I cannot do something like:

```
for output in results:
   output[0].add_element(output[1])
```

since the instance of `class A` returned is another instance.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve my goal?

Comment: For the second considered solution, what do you mean you can't use it "since the object of type A returned is another object"?

Comment: In one iteration I could call more than once the solve with the same object of type A and get more than 2 results for the same object. So, using the output[0] returned and doing  output[0].add_b_element(output[1]) for each element in results would add to 2 different objects of type A.

Comment: So you're saying that the `list_of_c_elements` can have duplicate `C` instances in it? Seems like that—avoiding adding a b element twice—would be a problem no matter what you do. Note class `A` doesn't have a method named `add_b_element()`.

Comment: list_of_c_elements contains C instances. Each C instance is created using one instance of class A and other parameters. Calling the solve() returns an element for each of two or more C instances that needs to be added to the same A instance.

Comment: To which two `C` instances should the b element be added? `solve()` is only passed one `C` argument.

Comment: the goal of C is: given A and other data to return an element of type B. I could hence have different instances of type C that return different elements of type B to be added to the same element of type A.

Comment: In that case you need for `solve()` to return the `A` instance that the b element should be added to—since it's apparently not always `c.a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` could additionally hold `id(a)` in a member and you can generate an index dictionary `{id(a): a}` if necessary. Be aware that all calls of `id()` must of course happen in the main process to produce usable results.